# How do I install third-party binaries in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What should I do in order to install third party programs such as imagemagick on Elastic Beanstalk so I can use them from my nodejs web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk will read configuration files from the `.ebextensions` directory in your application source bundle.  You can create configuration files there that customize many aspects of the EC2 instances that get created to run your application.

Here is an example config file that would install the latest ImageMagick version on your EC2 instances:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    ImageMagick: []
```

See the full AWS documentation here for more ways to customize your environment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html